# Lambda: uncaptured objects in unevaluated context

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++17

I'd appreciate a pointer to the Standard paragraph stating that the [following code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IgTZSwWG1O2BAzy5) is well-formed:

```
int main() {
    int var = 0;
    return [] { return sizeof(var); }(); // var is not captured!
}
```

Similar example appears e.g. in § 8.4.5.2, but I could not find any verbal description of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's specified in terms of when an entity *must* be captured, rather than in terms of when it may not.

> **[expr.prim.lambda.capture]** (with some omissions)
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda.capture#8) ... If a lambda-expression or an instantiation of the function
>   call operator template of a generic lambda odr-uses this or a variable
>   with automatic storage duration from its reaching scope, that entity
>   shall be captured by the lambda-expression. ...
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> void f1(int i) {
>   int const N = 20;
>   auto m1 = [=]{
>     int const M = 30;
>     auto m2 = [i]{
>       int x[N][M];          // OK: N and M are not odr-used
>       // ...
>     };
>   };
>   // ...
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

The key in your code sample is that `var` is not odr-used, because it is an unevaluated operand. As such, it does not need to be captured.